# Can i run an installed (using wine) windows executable file at startup?

Tags: wine, startup-applications

I have Palm desktop for windows running under wine. OS is Ubuntu 11.10. I have no problem executing the program, but would like to launch it during startup. Any advice gratefully received

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your `Startup Applications` (look for it on your dash):

`wine "<pathtoyourapplication"`

You will have to know where your application is (usually inside your `/home/.wine/drive_c` folder, look for it) but after adding it your application will run on startup.

Answer (score 1):

Click the **dashboard home button** and type in "start up applications" (without the quotes) and you should be able to open the **Startup Applications** program.

Setting a Windows program to run at startup via Wine is as easy as adding a startup application with a command that's something like this:

```
wine "/home/jeffy/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/herp/derp.exe"
```

Here the quotation marks are important, as without them, spaces would not register properly as part of the text in the command.

Obviously, you'll have to put the path to your .exe file instead of the sample path I put, but that should be a start. If I'm not mistaken, Wine comes with a tool to browse your fake C drive so it should be easy to find the program you're looking for.